# response.forEach is not a function ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Using ajax to pull data from mysql with php and javascript im getting a function error of response.forEach is not a function and I seen lots of people have posted about this but none of their resolutions have helped me or im writing it wrong, i have added the php and ajax code aswell as the array that is being retrieved.

array result:

```
{query1: Array(6), query2: Array(17)}
query1
:
Array(3)
0
:
{beacon: "81", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-03-12", counter: "40"}
1
:
{beacon: "69", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-03-12", counter: "39"}
2
:
{beacon: "257", location: "YELLOW", date: "2018-03-12", counter: "23"}
:
__proto__
:
Array(0)
query2
:
Array(5)
0
:
{beacon: "10", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "01.38"}
1
:
{beacon: "101", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "10.36"}
2
:
{beacon: "111", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "23.48"}
3
:
{beacon: "119", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "00.06"}
4
:
{beacon: "16", location: "YELLOW", delivery_avg: "00.00"}
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
```

ajax code:

```
   $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });
```

php code:

```
$sql1 = 'SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
beacon,location,date,
COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 40 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;';
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$rows1 = $result1->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sql2 = "SELECT beacon,location,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)), '%i.%s') 
AS `delivery_avg` 
FROM `test`.`test` 
where date = CURDATE()
and time > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
group by beacon";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$rows2 = $result2->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


$result = array(
'query1' => $rows1,
'query2' => $rows2,
);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: in  jquery, which is not named ajax as you seem to think, there is no foreach but an each() function.

Comment: Try like: `$.each(data.data, function(k, v) {    /// do stuff    });`

Comment: so where i have .forEach should i change that?

Comment: its dont work because you get object {query1: Array(6), query2: Array(17)} but not array.
you can use 
$.each(object, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it

```
$.each(object, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Your code be  $.each(response, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value);
});